# MVVMCross default binding mode used in a project

Tags: xamarin, binding, mvvmcross

I inherited a Xamarin MVVMCross project from another developer. I was wondering how can I get the default binding mode used and how I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MvvmCross the default [binding mode](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-binding-modes) is usual `Two-Way` when using bindings defined by MvvmCross (Virtual property bindings/Custom bindings). Native properties will usual be `One-Way` as by default there is no return mechanism (View to ViewModel).

***Notes from [MvvmCross Custom binding](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-binding-modes):***

> Where MvvmCross had created new bindings, then this [Two-Way binding] is very often the
>   default binding mode MvvmCross tries to use.

With the exception being Windows and Xaml:

> In Windows/Xaml, this [One-Way binding] is very often the default binding mode - so it
>   is the mode used when no other is selected.

[**Swiss binding syntax**](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-swiss)

```
, Mode=$WhichMode$
```

where `$WhichMode$` is one of:

- OneWay
- OneWay
- ToSource
- TwoWay
- OneTime
- Default

Example using Android AXML

```
local:MvxBind="Text UserName, Mode=OneWay"
```

[**Fluent binding syntax**](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-fluent)

Using code base binding you can use:

```
OneWay()
TwoWay()
OneWayToSource()
OneTime()
```

Example:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(cardLabel)
    .For(v => v.Text)
    .To(vm => vm.UserName)
    .OneWay();
set.Apply();
```

Comment: Does exist a method to set the default mode just in one point? I would line to avoid changing all the bindings in every xml layout file

Comment: No, as the default mode for binding various due to the property type, i.e. native properties by default can not send change events to the View Model, but MvvmCross custom binding can have bi-directional bindings. So in short setting mode to `TwoWay` on a native property will not make it a `Two-Way` binding, a custom binding will have to be used.